# Infinite loop in python - why?

Tags: python

I'm using the code

```
fibList=[1]

def fib(n1, n2):
    n3 = n1+n2
    n1=n2
    n2=n3

num1=1
num2=2

while(num2<4000000):
    fib(num1,num2)
        if (num2%2==0):
            fibList.append(num2)
total = sum(fibList)

print total
```

in an online compiler, repl.it. It was going and going and not giving a solution, so I typed the line `print n3` right below the `n3=` line in the definition of the `fib` function. It gave 3, over and over again, and it crashed before I could stop the program. So obviously there's some kind of infinite loop somewhere (at least, obviously in my mind; it could not be an infinite loop, I suppose, but I'm pretty sure it is). The question is where. I don't really understand why there'd be an infinite loop.

This is not, by the way, a homework question, but a problem I'm doing for fun. The `fib` function is supposed to calculate Fibonacci numbers, and the second part isolate the even ones less than four million, and then at the end calculate the sum.

What I want to know is where the infinite loop is coming in and what I can do to fix it. Thanks!

Comment: please fix the indentation in your code snippet

Comment: where are you changing the value of `num2` in your loop?

Comment: calling `fib` **does not** change values of n1 and n2 outside of function body.

Comment: The values of num1 and num2 never change....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass a variable by reference?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference)

Comment: The `fib` function just assigns values to the _local_ `n1`, `n2`, `n3` variables. This has no effect outside of the function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`n1`, `n2` and `n3` are local variables and have nothing in common with `num1` and `num2` in the outer scope, despite their initial value. You have to `return` the value and assign these results to `num1` and `num2` again.

```
def fib(n1, n2):
    n3 = n1+n2
    n1=n2
    n2=n3
    return n1, n2

num1=1
num2=2
fibList=[1]
while num2<4000000:
    num1, num2 = fib(num1,num2)
    if num2%2==0:
        fibList.append(num2)
total = sum(fibList)

print total
```

Comment: Thank you; this helped a lot. Sorry I didn't accept sooner!